# I can't find my segmentation fault: 11 error

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am new to C and wanted to break the series of videos to try a project, but I am stuck on a segmentation error. I get that that means I am trying to access memory I'm not allowed to, but I don't see the issue... I have a lot of code so I'll paste the parts that seem like they might be causing the problem and take out the includes. I am making a command-line text adventure game where two players can choose their name, class, and race (and currently the game ends after it asks them for the input). I appreciate it:

***main.c***

```
int main() {
    // See term dimesions

    // Create Player
    struct User* Player;
    CreatePlayer(Player);

    // Create Player
    struct User* Player2;
    CreatePlayer(Player2);

    return 0;
}
```

***story.c***

```
void CreatePlayer(struct User* Player) {

    char name[MAXINPUT];
    char class[MAXINPUT];
    char race[MAXINPUT];

    // Ask for name
    printf("%sWhat is your name?\n:\t", KNRM);
    getInput(name);
    printf("%sHello %s!\n", KNRM, name);

    {
    // Ask for class
    char question[] = "What is your class (Type '1' for Fighter or '2' for Mage)?\n:\t";
    char options[] = "12";
    char coorilations[][MAXINPUT] = {"Fighter", "Mage"};

    questionLoop(question, options, coorilations, class);
    InitializeClass(Player, class);
    printf("%sYou are now a %s!\n", KNRM, class);
    }

    {
    // Ask for race
    char question[] = "What is your race (Type '1' for Human or '2' for Elf)?\n:\t";
    char options[] = "12";
    char coorilations[][MAXINPUT] = {"Human", "Elf"};

    questionLoop(question, options, coorilations, race);
    printf("%sYou are now a %s!\n", KNRM, race);
    }

    strcpy(Player->name, name); 
    strcpy(Player->race, race);
}
```

**modules.c**

```
void InitializeClass(struct User* Player, char* class) {

    if (compare(class, "Fighter")) {
        strcpy(Player->class.name, "Fighter");
        Player->class.maxHealth = 10;
        Player->class.health = 10;
        Player->class.strength = 7;
    } else if (compare(class, "Mage")) {
        strcpy(Player->class.name, "Mage");
        Player->class.maxHealth = 7;
        Player->class.health = 7;
        Player->class.strength = 10;
    }
}

void getInput(char res[]) {
    int i = 0;
    int c;

    printf("%s", KMAG);
    c = getchar();
    while(c != '\n') {
        res[i++] = c;
        c = getchar();
    }

    res[i] = '\0';
}

void questionLoop(char question[], char options[], char coorilations[][MAXINPUT], char var[]) {
    printf("%s-------------------------------\n", KGRN);
    printf("%s%s", KNRM, question);
    getInput(var);
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(options); i++) {
        if (options[i] == var[0] && var[1] == '\0') {
            strcpy(var, coorilations[i]);
            printf("%s", KNRM);
            return;
        }
    }
    printf("%sSorry that was not an option...\n", KNRM);
    questionLoop(question, options, coorilations, var);
}

int compare(char one[], char two[]) {
    for (int i = 0; one[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (one[i] != two[i]) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

**modules.h**

```
#ifndef HEADER_FILE
#define HEADER_FILE

#define MAXINPUT 20

#define KNRM  "\x1B[0m"
#define KRED  "\x1B[31m"
#define KGRN  "\x1B[32m"
#define KYEL  "\x1B[33m"
#define KBLU  "\x1B[34m"
#define KMAG  "\x1B[35m"
#define KCYN  "\x1B[36m"
#define KWHT  "\x1B[37m"

// Classes
struct Class {
    char name[MAXINPUT];
    int strength;
    int health;
    int maxHealth;
};

// User struct
struct User {
    char name[MAXINPUT];
    char race[MAXINPUT];
    struct Class class;
};

// Utilities
void getInput(char res[]);
void questionLoop(char question[], char options[], char coorilations[][MAXINPUT], char var[]);
int compare(char one[], char two[]);

// Game Setup Functions
void CreatePlayer(struct User*);
void InitializeClass(struct User* Player, char* class);

// Game Functions
void GameLoop(struct User*);
void ViewStats(struct User*);

#endif
```

Comment: This appears to be C code, not C++.

Comment: You are never allocating any memory for `Player`(s)

Comment: Tip: Use `char*` in your structures and avoid fixed-length buffers. They're wasteful, especially in large arrays of these things. You should also match your `Create` function names with the thing they create. `CreateUser` makes more sense here, or renaming `User` to `Player` to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never allocate memory for your `Player`, so from you main method, you call `CreatePlayer()`, which in turns calls `questionLoop()`, which does nothing in terms of memory allocations, and then `InitializeClass()`, which does (amongst others):

```
strcpy(Player->class.name, "Fighter");
```

but `Player` doesn't exist, since you haven't actually create it, you haven't allocated for it, and thus a Segmentation fault occurs (here on the very next lines of that method).

Try dynamically allocating memory using [`malloc()`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) (e.g. `struct User* player = malloc(sizeof(struct User));`, and don't forget to [`free()`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/) it when you are done.

Answer (score 1):

This declares a pointer:

```
struct User* Player;
```

It is, however, completely uninitialized. It cannot be used before you populate it with something. The `CreatePlayer` function should assume this responsibility.

Typically these functions look like:

```
struct User* CreatePlayer() {
  struct User *player = malloc(sizeof(struct User));

  if (player == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }

  // Do stuff with player

  return player;
}
```

Where that pattern can be used for any "Create" type function.